# Is my device unrecoverable without factory reset? - com.andoird.phone stopped

Tags: recovery-mode, data-recovery, cache, mi-a2

Yesterday I took my Xiaomi Mi A2 from my pocket and saw a warning screen (text-only) telling me the device couldnt start and if the issue persisted I might need to do a factory reset and wipe all my data. I clicked try again.

After starting, my device displays an error message - "process com.android.phone stopped". When I try to unlock the phone it starts rebooting after a few seconds. When I slide down the top tool bar the device also starts to reboot.

I searched for a solution but didn't find a fix that works for me. Some of the suggestions relating to a simmilar issue (but the error message in those cases starts with "Unfortunately" and the devices seem to be somewhat servicable) suggest wiping cache, contacts or SIM tools but all of those are inaccessible to me because the device reboots all the time. Another solution for wiping the cache is using `adb` command line tool. But `adb` doesn't "see" devices without USB debugging enabled - which again I can't enable because I cannot access the settings menu (reboots). `fastboot` seems to be able to delete cache with `fastboot erase cache` but I'm prevented from doing this because of an error - `FAILED (remote: 'Erase is not allowed in Lock State')`. I'm not sure if this Lock State gets unlocked with `fastboot oem unlock` but from what I understand that would wipe my device anyway.

Finding all of this out took quite some time so at this point I don't know what else to do as I have very little knowledge about this area. Is there any way to at least attempt to clean the cache or will I have to go for the factory reset? I'm not entirely sure if I have all the Google Authenticator recovery codes so I'm hesitant to do so.

I've had an old iPhone 4 for some 4 years and I've never had to invest so much time into that so you can imagine why this frustrates me at this point.

Comment: something might have caused a system error, you have no choice but to factory reset or re-flash the firmware, or find the root of the error. This error is caused by varying situation so it is hard say for now what might have happened.

Comment: As for wiping the cache. You could try from recovery enter recovery: from `device off state hold the power button and the volume up bottom at the same time. Then once recovery has started release` you should next see `a no command screen, hold down power button and then press volume up button once. Immediately after that, let go both buttons and you will enter stock recovery.` there might be an option for the cache. Use the volume buttons to navigate. Use the power button to select option. Also, you are correct on the lock state assumption your bootloader is locked.

Comment: @BoLawson Yea I found about the android recovery screen already but it doesn't feature an option to wipe the cache partition. From what I've read that has been removed in some update at with version 7... Something to do with seamless updates?